# Password protect existing HSQLDB DB

Tags: java, database, hsqldb

I need to be able to password protect an existing HSQLDB.

Looks like the HSQLDB documentation provides insights into how to initially setup a HSQLDB with a username and password - but how to go about protecting an existing HSQLDB?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SET PASSSWORD command. This is covered in the Guide:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/accesscontrol-chapt.html#acc_statements

You connect to the database then set the password.